# Passing URL parameters to render

Tags: django, url, parameters

I have a method that inserts a new `Comment` into the base, and after doing so, it redirects back to the previous post, which can be any. So, to do that, I made the following rule:

> `return redirect(reverse('blog:post', args = (post_id,)))`

With it, the page is redirected back to the previous `Post` being read, by passing to the URL the `id`.

The problem is now in case the form is not valid. I want to display error messages, but I think that the way it is now, the form is being recreated, erasing any message. So, in the `else` condition, I want to, instead of redirecting, rendering it again and showing the messages. I've done it like this:

> `return render(request, 'blog/post.html', post_id = post_id)`

But then, I need to get back to the same page I was, regardless the `id` in the parameter. I need to pass the `post_id` as I did in the `redirect` function, but I can't find a way.

This is the whole method:

```
def write_comment(request, post_id):
    """
    Write a new comment to a post
    """
    form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        post = Post.objects.get(pk = post_id)
        post.n_comments += 1
        post.save()

        comment = Comment()
        comment.comment = request.POST['comment']
        comment.created_at = timezone.now()
        comment.modified_at = timezone.now()
        comment.post_id = post_id
        comment.user_id = 2
        comment.save()

        return redirect(reverse('blog:post', args = (post_id,)))
    else:
        # Need to pass the parameter here, in order to not recreate the form
        return render(request, 'blog/post.html')
```

My class view used to display the `Post`, depending on its `id`, by the URL:

```
url(r'^post/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.GetPostView.as_view(), name = 'post'),
```

And the `GetPostView`:

```
class GetPostView(TemplateView):
    """
    Render the view for a specific post and lists its comments
    """
    template_name = 'blog/post.html'

    def get(self, request, id):
        return render(request, self.template_name, {
            'post': Post.objects.get(pk = id),
            'comments': Comment.objects.filter(post = id).order_by('-created_at'),
            'form': CommentForm()
    })
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should be passing the form as a context variable (context parameter).

```
render(request, 'blog/post.html', context={"form": form})
```

You might also want to re-organize things.  I would combine the comment-processing logic with `GetPostView`.  I would try moving the logic you have in `get` over to `get_context_data`, which will be used when rendering get/post.  Then add a `post` method (instead of `write_comment`, although you could certainly call that from `post`).  In there, if you need to render the page as is, you simply try calling the `super` version of the `post` method.

```
class GetPostView(TemplateView):
    """
    Render the view for a specific post and lists its comments
    """
    template_name = 'blog/post.html'

    def get(self, request, id):
        self.request = request
        self.id = id

        return super(GetPostView, self).get(request, self.id)

    def post(self, request, id):
        """
        Process comment
        """
        self.form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)

        if self.form.is_valid():
            post = Post.objects.get(pk = id)
            post.n_comments += 1
            post.save()

            comment = Comment()
            comment.comment = request.POST['comment']
            comment.created_at = timezone.now()
            comment.modified_at = timezone.now()
            comment.post_id = id
            comment.user_id = 2
            comment.save()

            return redirect(reverse('blog:post', args = (id,)))
        else:
            return self.get(request, id)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        form = self.form if hasattr(self, 'form') else CommentForm()

        return {
                'post': Post.objects.get(pk = self.id),
                'comments': Comment.objects.filter(post = self.id).order_by('-created_at'),
                'form': form
        }
```

Disclaimer: I'm not running this code, so a stupid mistake is likely.  If you point them out, I'll try to clean it up.

Comment: Almost. The message is finally being displayed, but I still need to receive the `post_id`. The page is this url `/post/<post_id>/`, and I need to render the page on this same page.

Comment: So when your render the form validation errors, you want the post as well?  I don't see anything for the post in this method (aside from the redirect).  Is there another method for it?

Comment: Yes, the class view for displaying the post according to the id in the url. Look my edited question, please.

Comment: I just edited my answer with what I think you should try.  Have a look.

Comment: Found one stupid mistake myself.  The `get_context_data` didn't have a `self` argument.

Comment: Also, this answer assumes Python 2.7, not 3.X.  I have less practice in 3.X, but I realize adoption is increasing.

And I'm heading off to bed.  I hope this was helpful.  I'll have a look in the morning to see if you have any more questions.

Comment: Doesn't matter what I do, I always get `get_context_data() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106875/discussion-between-bpscott-and-gabriel-m-fernandes).